# Ruby on Rails loop returning phantom objects in iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Ruby on Rails app returns 'phantom' objects when iterating through my loop. The issue here is I have a SQL command in my Controller file that sets my locations array like so:

```
    @locations = Location.select(
        'distinct location_address_1,location_city
        ,location_state,location_zip').where(
        '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item_data 
        WHERE item_data.location_id = locations.id)')
```

Problem is I get extra blanks when iterating through in my view file. I have seen this question asked a few times with no solution. Does anyone know why this code written in my view.html.erb

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>    
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>
        <% @locations.find_each do |location| %>
        <tr>                                
            <td>1</td>                              
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3<td>
            <td>4</td>                                                          
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

Outputs as this in my browser:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td/>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As shown above, I get the extra blank even when hardcoding my data.

Answer (score 1):

You have a td without closing tag(3rd one). Try after correcting it.

Comment: Wow, that's it. And pretty embarrassing. Thanks!